# How to filter bbPress replies (content)?

Tags: filters, bbpress

I wanted to know, how to filter bbPress replies ? ( i mean as the typical post's the_content filter..)

this one doesnt work:

```
add_filter('the_content','custommm_functiooonn');   
function custommm_functiooonn($content){
  return 'hiiiiiiii'.$content;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## The solution found:

```
add_filter('bbp_get_topic_content', 'custommm_functiooonn');
add_filter('bbp_get_reply_content', 'custommm_functiooonn');
function custommm_functiooonn($content){
  return 'hiiiiiiii'.$content;
  }
```